# Why does texts_to_sequences() output as an empty array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to predict using a pre trained model.

and the texts_to_sequences(twt) returns and empty array. Therefore, the prediction is always negative. for all the inputs.

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
twt=['happy']
#vectorizing the tweet by the pre-fitted tokenizer instance
twt = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(twt)
print(twt)
#padding the tweet to have exactly the same shape as `embedding_2` input
twt = pad_sequences(twt, maxlen=50, dtype='int32', value=0)
print(twt)
sentiment = model.predict(twt,batch_size=1,verbose = 2)[0]
print(sentiment)
if(np.argmax(sentiment) == 0):
    print("negative")
elif (np.argmax(sentiment) == 1):
    print("positive")
```

Output :

```
[[]]
[0.89889544 0.10110457]
negative
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Did the pre-fitter tokenizer instance have any input containing the word happy? In other words, if you run `t.word_index.get("happy", "word not in the vocabulary")`, what do you get?

Comment: yes it is included. I checked with the data set as well

Comment: Good (: What values do you get for `t.num_words` and `t.oov_token`? If `t.oov_token` is `None` and `t.num_words` < `t.word_index.get("happy", "word not in the vocabulary")` that would explain the empty array. If that is the case, two possible solutions are to increase `t.num_words` and/or set `oov_token = "<OOV>"` before fitting the tokenizer to texts.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue all you need to do is pass list in both of these functions **tokenizer.fit_on_texts** and **tokenizer.texts_to_sequences**.

example:
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(**[test_word]**)

```
model = ks.models.load_model('trained')
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
test_word ="This is soo cool"
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([test_word])
tw = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([test_word])
print('tw: ', tw)
```